# Why Can't I use Modules in VS Code After I Install One With Pip

Tags: python, pip

I'm new to python and VS Code and have been playing around recently for both fun and an attempt to raise my skills. However, when working on certain projects I haven't had default access to the modules I've needed such as dearpygui, so to install them I've used pip

```
pip install dearpygui
```

However, after having done this I still seemingly don't have access to them in VS code or at my terminal. In VS code I get a warning telling me

```
Import "dearpygui" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)
```

What exactly am I doing wrong when importing these modules? If anybody could give me a hand I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: try `from dearpygui import *` and import your modules. If you know the functions you want to import, you can replace the `*` (the `*`  means import all functions in the module) with the function name

Comment: I've tried that in my code, but whenever I run it I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dearpygui'

Comment: Where did you type `pip install dearpygui` also show the output of typing `pip install dearpygui`

Comment: Have you tried using:
    from dearpygui.core import *
    from dearpygui.simple import *